# OrderByDescending with a date from another table(s)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Hopefully this question is not to confusing. Basically I'm looking for pointers on how to **OrderByDecending** with a date from relational tables. I have constructed a basic method that looks like it could possibly work but I'm getting errors:

> DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
>   Parameter name: key

I understand what this is saying but I'm not entirely sure how to fix using Linq method syntax.

```
public BusinessEntities.Application GetLastUpdatedAppliction(int userID)
{
    return context.tbl_User_To_Application
                            .Where(x => x.UserID == userID)
                            .OrderByDescending
                                        (o => o.tbl_Application.tbl_ApplicationChanges
                                            .Where(oo => oo.ApplicationID == o.ApplicationID)
                                            .Select(s => s.ChangeDate))
                            .ThenByDescending(t => t.DateAdded)
                            .Select(y => new BusinessEntities.Application
                            {
                                ApplicationID = y.tbl_Application.ApplicationID,
                                ApplicationName = y.tbl_Application.ApplicationName
                            }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Basically I have a cross reference table that binds a user to a specific application(Website) Then inside I need to nest into two tables to get the latest changes to the Application with a "ChangesDate". So ideally this would return the last updated application. Then obviously populates my DTO.

I'm still trying to get to grips with Linq method syntax so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Tez Wingfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to order by the last application change date:

```
(...)
.OrderByDescending(o => 
   o.tbl_Application.tbl_ApplicationChanges
      .Where(ac => ac.ApplicationID == o.ApplicationID)
      .OrderByDescending(ac => ac.ChangeDate)
      .First()
      .Select(ac => ac.ChangeDate)
)
(...)
```

Comment: Hi, Your First() and Select() are the wrong way round and also First() will throw and error if their are nulls. FirstOrDefault() will full back to another element in the list or go to the next oderby. Please could you elaborate on your answer? where I was going wrong? What was happening in the code etc? Just helps me and future readers. Never the less after I tweaked it, it worked perfectly. Great work!

Comment: @TezWingfield
1) If you expect that First() will throw an exception, then you will expect than there is no records in tbl_ApplicationChanges related to tbl_Application.ApplicationID. In that case you don't have the value of tbl_ApplicationChanges.ChangeDate you want to sort by.
2) First() will not throw an exception because (in your case) it is translated to SQL, not evaluated.

Comment: @TezWingfield Also I suppose `.Where(oo => oo.ApplicationID == o.ApplicationID)` is unnecessery. Try to remove and check how it works.